# Unable to use scrapy to login into Instagram

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to use scrapy to log into Instagram to scan and read comments but I cant seem to be able to login looks likr the request gets blocked by a bot. Is there a better way to attempt the scrapy login?

```
url = 'https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login'
request = scrapy.Request(url,method='GET')
fetch(request)
2024-02-12 12:39:37 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt] DEBUG: Forbidden by robots.txt: <GET https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login>
```

Yes I know I dont have user name and password declared here but I cant even get to the page source.

Comment: you will likely need to use a browser automation tool.

Comment: Any reason why this cant be done with out automation tool?

Comment: This wouldn't be easy. But first you need to disable `ROBOTSTXT_OBEY`.

Comment: If all you are trying to do is login... then there is no reason.  But crawling social media tends to be complicated without the ability to render javascript.